# How to tidy a datset in R that has every other even column as a header value?

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data looks something like:

```
DATE,09/02/21 20:48:00, VAL1, 123, VAL2, 789
DATE,09/02/21 20:48:15, VAL1, 456, VAL2, 1011
```

Is there an easy way to convert it to something like:

```
DATE,              VAL1, VAL2
09/02/21 20:48:00, 123,  789
09/02/21 20:48:15, 456,  1011
```

I haven't been able to find a concrete solution in the tidyverse that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R suffices here.

```r
txt
# [1] "DATE,09/02/21 20:48:00, VAL1, 123, VAL2, 789\nDATE,09/02/21 20:48:15, VAL1, 456, VAL2, 1011"
x <- read.csv(text = txt, header = FALSE)
### x <- read.csv("path/to/yourfile.csv", header = FALSE)
x
#     V1                V2    V3  V4    V5   V6
# 1 DATE 09/02/21 20:48:00  VAL1 123  VAL2  789
# 2 DATE 09/02/21 20:48:15  VAL1 456  VAL2 1011

evens <- !seq_along(x) %% 2
evens
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
names(x)[evens] <- sapply(x[!evens], `[[`, 1)
x <- x[,evens]

x
#                DATE  VAL1  VAL2
# 1 09/02/21 20:48:00   123   789
# 2 09/02/21 20:48:15   456  1011
```

This assumes that the headers are invariant; that is, `x$V3` is always `"VAL1"`, etc.